# increment a binary number without arithmetic manipulations

Tags: code-golf, string, arithmetic, binary

**Input:** binary string

**Output:** binary string that represents the binary input + 1

**Example:** Given `10111` as an input, output `11000`

**Limitations:** Can't use arithmetic operators or functions (like `+ - * /`)

**Criterion:** code-golf, the shortest code wins the big imaginary award.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/204040/58563)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! To be valid, a challenge needs to have a winning criterion. This is usually [`code-golf`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info), but some other ones are commonly used as well. Another problem is that [Do X without Y is often problematic](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/58563).

Comment: Also, please use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) next time before posting a challenge, to get feedback on it.

Comment: Can you clarify what counts as arithmetic operators, and what input/output methods you would allow?

Comment: I assumed arithmetic operators are the usual gang of four `+ - * /` and possibly `^ %` (power and modulus) You should perhaps specify if `001` should result in `010` or if `10` is also ok.

Comment: Another question is whether `1` should give `0` or `10`

Comment: @Wezl Challenge says nothing about overflow and keeping the number of digits so I've assumed `10` in that case.

Comment: Usually boolean operators are not considered as arithmetic operators in programming, and considering that arithmetic operations can (and are actually) be performed by combination of boolean operators, did you mean to forbid them too or is it intended we can use these combinations?

Comment: I think it would be clearer and not much easier if arithmetic was allowed, because very few languages have golfy binary i/o.

Comment: Why closed / off-topic without explanation? Seems to be a decent code-golf question to me, albeit perhaps on the easy side.

Comment: @KjetilS. The problem with the question is the “can’t use arithmetic operators or functions” line. As stated above by Arnauld, this makes the question “Do X without Y” and unfortunately, it’s a classic example of the problem with that: what constitutions a “arithmetic function”? Either the OP provides an exact list of banned operations (which is still problematic as not every language has those operations defined in the same way), or they clarify what exactly an arithmetic function is, which experience has shown is difficult/impossible to do objectively

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing – Yes, I think he/she should have listed `+ - * /` but I still think closing without explanation is the bigger problem of those two. (I would have thought arithmetic operators shouldn't need detailing to the typical visitor in this corner of the internet, just as "binary string" also shouldn't need it which he/she also used but no one reacted on)

Comment: @KjetilS. Just limiting the operations to `+-*/` probably won’t achieve what the OP wants - a basically Jelly solution would be to convert from binary, increment, convert to binary, and I’m sure many other languages would be the same. The explanation for closing is implied via Arnauld’s and Redwolf’s unanswered questions, and something as vague as “arithmetic functions” *absolutely* needs to defined, in the same way that something such as “write a pointer to” would need to be clarified/improved

Answer (score 2):

## GNU sed [<4.3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51323/tips-for-golfing-in-sed#comment268984_51352), <s><sup>49 46 44 34</sup></s> 30 bytes

```perl
s/.*/0&M/ # prepend 0 and append mark
: # label
s/0M/1/ # 0 incremented is 1
s/1M/M0/ # 1 incremented is 0 and the one to the left is incremented
t # if anything just changed, repeat until it doesn't (the M has disappeared)
```

(comments and all whitespace other that newlines are just for explanation)

This takes any amount of newline-separated binary numbers and increments each, it might give a number with leading 0s.

[try it online](https://sed.js.org/)

Comment: Some parts of the question, such as whether there are negative numbers, were unspecified. Sed has no arithmetic, so this is guaranteed to not use them.

Comment: Doesn't work for repunits.

Comment: @Neil fixed, but the question doesn't specify what to do on overflow, such as whether `11111111` is -1.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 38 bytes

```perl
s/0$/1/||s/0?(1+)$/1 .(0 x length$1)/e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79Y30BF31C/pgbIsNcw1NYE8hT0NAwUKhRyUvPSSzJUDDX1U///NwABLhBhCCQNDQ25DEEChgYgFghz/csvKMnMzyv@r1uQAwA)

Basically: If(last digit is zero){ change it to 1} else {change the last
consecutive 1's (with possibly a 0 ahead of them) with a 1 and a count of zeros that is the same number as the number of 1's matched at the end of the line.

Example input lines:
00000
00001
00111
1000
1011
111
1

Example output lines:
00001
00010
01000
1001
1100
1000
10

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 37 bytes

Or one less byte with this if it's ok to not preserve leading 0's (i.e. `0001` → `10`)

```perl
printf"%b\n",length 1 .(1x oct"0b$_")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1JNSkmT0knJzUvvSRDwVBBT8OwQiE/uUTJIEklXknz/38DEOACEYZA0tDQkMsQJGBoAGKBMNe//IKSzPy84v@6eTkA)